# Смена заголовка в хедере (внутри дефолтного лейаута) в зависимости от открываемой страницы, NUXT JS

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

Я использую NUXT JS и сейчас у меня есть необходимость динамически менять заголовок в хедере (хедер лежит в дефолтном лейауте) в зависимости от того, на какой странице я нахожусь. Нашла метод head(), похоже он мне и нужен..Но исходя из данных, какие есть в документации, я не могу сделать то, что хочу. Не понимаю что, куда и к чему применяется, если в моем случае хедер, где нужно менять заголовок, лежит в лейаутах.

[ССЫЛКА НА ДОКУМЕНТАЦИЮ NUXT](https://nuxtjs.org/api/pages-head#the-head-method)
 Подскажите пожалуйста что и как. Буду благодарна

Answer (score 1):

Не лучшее решение, но есть вариант. Сразу скажу, если куда лучший способ, но этот первый пришел в голову. Можно создать объект в layout.vue, и после чего сделать на него глобальную переменную, какая будет содержать ссылку. А когда страница прогружается в изменять ее как хотите.

```
if(typeof window.__layout_params === 'object')
   window.__layout_params.title = 'New page title';
```